# Relation does not exist but no migrations to apply Django

Tags: python, django, django-tests

I'm finally trying to build some tests (I should have done this long ago). But whenever I try

```
python manage.py test
```

I get

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "Customers Table" does not exist
```

Along with a stacktrace that gives no indication which model it is referring to (many models relate to Customers Table). I commented everything out of `test.py` - so the only thing `python manage.py test` is doing is trying to build that test db.

I guess the question is around migrations because I imagine that's how it's building the test database. I am not sure how to even begin digging around in my 50+ migrations to find where/when I made this relation. Is there a way to purge/clean migrations without messing things up too much? Then I could create a new migration that reflects current-state accurately without preserving the sins of my past migrations.

Comment: You can do that but IMHO it involves manually entries from your database. Wouldn't it be easier to create a copy of your project (without the migrations) and start freshly from there?

Comment: So would the main benefit to creating a copy be that it preserves the migrations? Otherwise what's the difference? Thanks.

Comment: What I meant is: Start a new project, copy in your apps and settings and migrate the 'new' project. Manually taking back migrations by fiddling with the database can easily cause problems

Comment: Oh I see - thanks - that might work